# On site load Visual composer "stretch row" not working properly. content going to out of screen

Tags: jquery, wordpress, visual-composer

I've set VC row as stretch for full screen. but on site load i noticed VC adding css "left" value to section div. As you can clearly can see in screenshot.
can you tell me what is main issue is here. I'm using Visual composer of latest version. 
[image: Please see this screenshot]

Comment: But after resizing window structure set to its original view. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution of problem. I hope it will help you too.

```
function bs_fix_vc_full_width_row(){
    var $fullrow = jQuery('[data-vc-full-width="true"]');
    jQuery.each($fullrow, function () {
        var $el = jQuery(this);
        var container_width = jQuery('.vc_page_holder').width();///site-main container width;

        var window_width = $el.width();

        if ($el.is('[data-vc-stretch-content="true"]')){
            var divleft = (window_width-container_width) /2;
            var spacUnit= divleft-15;
            $el.css('left', -spacUnit).css('right', '');
        }else{
            var Padleft = (jQuery(window).width() - container_width) / 2;
            console.log('container:'+container_width+' | RowWidth:'+window_width);
            var spacunit= Padleft-15;
            $el.css('padding-left',spacunit).css('padding-right',spacunit).css('left', -spacunit).css('right', '');
        }
    });


}

jQuery(document).on('vc-full-width-row', function () {
    bs_fix_vc_full_width_row();
});
```